# JSON loading/fetching properly but unable to display

Tags: java, android, json, xml, parsing

Checked my JSON fetching properly there is no error in that the parsing is done perfectly but app doesn't show any result (an empty list view shown).
Providing all my files if anyone can help me to solve this issue that would be great. 
Note: The app is not showing any error it is just showing blank list view.

WordActivity.java

```
package com.example.anandparmeetsingh.books;

import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WordActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Word>> {
    private static final int EARTHQUAKE_LOADER_ID = 1;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = WordActivity.class.getName();
    /**
     * URL for earthquake data from the USGS dataset
     */
    private static final String USGS_REQUEST_URL =
            "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2014-01-01&endtime=2014-01-02";
    /**
     * Adapter for the list of earthquakes
     */
    public WordAdapter mAdapter;
    private TextView mEmptyStateTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_word);
        // Get a reference to the LoaderManager, in order to interact with loaders.

        mAdapter = new WordAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Word>());


        ListView earthquakeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        // Create a new adapter that takes an empty list of earthquakes as input
        final WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Word>());


        // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
        // so the list can be populated in the user interface

        earthquakeListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Set an item click listener on the ListView, which sends an intent to a web browser
        // to open a website with more information about the selected earthquake.


        // Start the AsyncTask to fetch the earthquake data
        //mEmptyStateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        //earthquakeListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyStateTextView);
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // Get details on the currently active default data network
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        // If there is a network connection, fetch data
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            // Get a reference to the LoaderManager, in order to interact with loaders.
            LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();

            // Initialize the loader. Pass in the int ID constant defined above and pass in null for
            // the bundle. Pass in this activity for the LoaderCallbacks parameter (which is valid
            // because this activity implements the LoaderCallbacks interface).
            loaderManager.initLoader(EARTHQUAKE_LOADER_ID, null, this);
        } else {
            // Otherwise, display error
            // First, hide loading indicator so error message will be visible
            //View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
            //loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

             //Update empty state with no connection error message
            //mEmptyStateTextView.setText("No Connection");
        }

    }

    public Loader<List<Word>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new WordLoader(this, USGS_REQUEST_URL);
    }

    /**
     * {@link } to perform the network request on a background thread, and then
     * update the UI with the list of earthquakes in the response.
     * <p>
     * AsyncTask has three generic parameters: the input type, a type used for progress updates, and
     * an output type. Our task will take a String URL, and return an EarthquakeAdapter. We won't do
     * progress updates, so the second generic is just Void.
     * <p>
     * We'll only override two of the methods of AsyncTask: doInBackground() and onPostExecute().
     * The doInBackground() method runs on a background thread, so it can run long-running code
     * (like network activity), without interfering with the responsiveness of the app.
     * Then onPostExecute() is passed the result of doInBackground() method, but runs on the
     * UI thread, so it can use the produced data to update the UI.
     */

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Word>> loader, List<Word> earthquakes) {
        // Clear the adapter of previous earthquake data
        //View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
        //loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_earthquakes);
        mAdapter.clear();
        // If there is a valid list of {@link Earthquake}s, then add them to the adapter's
        // data set. This will trigger the ListView to update.
        if (earthquakes != null && !earthquakes.isEmpty()) {
            mAdapter.addAll(earthquakes);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Word>> loader) {
        // Loader reset, so we can clear out our existing data.
        mAdapter.clear();
    }


}
```

Word.java

```
package com.example.anandparmeetsingh.books;

public class Word {

    private String mMagnitude;
    private String mLocation;
    private Long mDate;
    private String mUrl;

    public Word(String magnitude, String location, String url) {
        mMagnitude = magnitude;
        mLocation = location;
        mUrl = url;


    }
    public Word(String magnitude, String location, Long date, String url) {
        mMagnitude = magnitude;
        mLocation = location;
        mDate = date;
        mUrl = url;


    }

    public String getMagnitude() {
        return mMagnitude;
    }

    public String geLocation() {
        return mLocation;
    }

    public Long getDate() {
        return mDate;
    }
    public String getUrl(){return mUrl;}




}
```

WordAdapter.java

```
package com.example.anandparmeetsingh.books;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by ParmeetSingh on 5/9/2017.
 */

public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {
    String primaryLocation;
    String locationOffset;
    String description;
    private static final String LOCATION_SEPARATOR = " of ";

    public WordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Word> words) {
        // Here, we initialize the ArrayAdapter's internal storage for the context and the list.
        // the second argument is used when the ArrayAdapter is populating a single TextView.
        // Because this is a custom adapter for two TextViews and an ImageView, the adapter is not
        // going to use this second argument, so it can be any value. Here, we used 0.
        super(context, 0, words);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.activity_list_display, parent, false);
        }
        // Get the {@link AndroidFlavor} object located at this position in the list
        Word currentWord = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView with view ID magnitude
        TextView magnitudeView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.magnitude);
        // Format the magnitude to show 1 decimal place

        // Display the magnitude of the current earthquake in that TextView
        magnitudeView.setText(description);

        String originalLocation = currentWord.geLocation();
        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_number
        TextView primaryLocationView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.primary_location);
        // Display the location of the current earthquake in that TextView
        primaryLocationView.setText(primaryLocation);

        // Find the TextView with view ID location offset
        TextView locationOffsetView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.location_offset);
        // Display the location offset of the current earthquake in that TextView
        locationOffsetView.setText(locationOffset);


        //Date dateObject = new Date(currentWord.getDate());

        // Find the TextView with view ID date
        TextView dateView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        // Format the date string (i.e. "Mar 3, 1984")
        //String formattedDate = formatDate(dateObject);
        // Display the date of the current earthquake in that TextView
        dateView.setText(primaryLocation);

        // Find the TextView with view ID time
        TextView timeView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        // Format the time string (i.e. "4:30PM")
        //String formattedTime = formatTime(locationOffset);
        // Display the time of the current earthquake in that TextView
        timeView.setText(locationOffset);


        return listItemView;
    }
    private String formatMagnitude(double magnitude) {
        DecimalFormat magnitudeFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
        return magnitudeFormat.format(magnitude);
    }
    /**
     * Return the formatted date string (i.e. "Mar 3, 1984") from a Date object.
     */
    private String formatDate(Date dateObject) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("LLL dd, yyyy");
        return dateFormat.format(dateObject);
    }
    private String formatTime(Date dateObject) {
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        return timeFormat.format(dateObject);
    }

}
```

WordLoader.java

```
package com.example.anandparmeetsingh.books;

import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.content.Context;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by ParmeetSingh on 5/9/2017.
 */

public class WordLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Word>> {

    /** Tag for log messages */
    private static final String LOG_TAG = WordLoader.class.getName();

    /** Query URL */
    private String mUrl;

    /**
     * Constructs a new {@link WordLoader}.
     *
     * @param context of the activity
     * @param url to load data from
     */
    public WordLoader(Context context, String url) {
        super(context);
        mUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        forceLoad();
    }

    /**
     * This is on a background thread.
     */
    @Override
    public List<Word> loadInBackground() {
        if (mUrl == null) {
            return null;
        }

        // Perform the network request, parse the response, and extract a list of earthquakes.
        List<Word> earthquakes = QueryUtils.fetchEarthquakeData(mUrl);
        return earthquakes;
    }
}
```

QueryUtils.java

```
package com.example.anandparmeetsingh.books;

import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by ParmeetSingh on 5/9/2017.
 */

public class QueryUtils {

    /**
     * Tag for the log messages
     */
    private static final String LOG_TAG = QueryUtils.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Create a private constructor because no one should ever create a {@link QueryUtils} object.
     * This class is only meant to hold static variables and methods, which can be accessed
     * directly from the class name QueryUtils (and an object instance of QueryUtils is not needed).
     */
    private QueryUtils() {

    }

    /**
     * Query the USGS dataset and return a list of {@link WordAdapter} objects.
     */
    public static List<Word> fetchEarthquakeData(String requestUrl) {
        // Create URL object
        URL url = createUrl(requestUrl);

        // Perform HTTP request to the URL and receive a JSON response back
        String jsonResponse = null;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            jsonResponse = makeHttpRequest(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem making the HTTP request.", e);
        }

        // Extract relevant fields from the JSON response and create a list of {@link EarthquakeAdapter}s
        List<Word> earthquake = extractFeatureFromJson(jsonResponse);

        // Return the list of {@link EarthquakeAdapter}s
        return earthquake;
    }

    /**
     * Returns new URL object from the given string URL.
     */
    private static URL createUrl(String stringUrl) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(stringUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem building the URL ", e);
        }
        return url;
    }

    /**
     * Make an HTTP request to the given URL and return a String as the response.
     */
    private static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
        String jsonResponse = "";

        // If the URL is null, then return early.
        if (url == null) {
            return jsonResponse;
        }

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // If the request was successful (response code 200),
            // then read the input stream and parse the response.
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
            } else {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem retrieving the earthquake JSON results.", e);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                // Closing the input stream could throw an IOException, which is why
                // the makeHttpRequest(URL url) method signature specifies than an IOException
                // could be thrown.
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    /**
     * Convert the {@link InputStream} into a String which contains the
     * whole JSON response from the server.
     */
    private static String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                output.append(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        return output.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Return a list of {@link WordAdapter} objects that has been built up from
     * parsing the given JSON response.
     */

    private static List<Word> extractFeatureFromJson(String earthquakeJSON) {
        // If the JSON string is empty or null, then return early.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(earthquakeJSON)) {
            return null;
        }

        // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding earthquakes to

        List<Word> earthquakes = new ArrayList<>();


        // Try to parse the JSON response string. If there's a problem with the way the JSON
        // is formatted, a JSONException exception object will be thrown.
        // Catch the exception so the app doesn't crash, and print the error message to the logs.
        try {


            // Create a JSONObject from the JSON response string
            JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(earthquakeJSON);
            // Extract the JSONArray associated with the key called "features",
            // which represents a list of features (or earthquakes).
            JSONArray earthquakeArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("features");

            // For each earthquake in the earthquakeArray, create an {@link EarthquakeAdapter} object
            for (int i = 0; i < earthquakeArray.length(); i++) {

                // Get a single earthquake at position i within the list of earthquakes
                JSONObject currentEarthquake = earthquakeArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // For a given earthquake, extract the JSONObject associated with the
                // key called "properties", which represents a list of all properties
                // for that earthquake.
                JSONObject properties = currentEarthquake.getJSONObject("properties");

                // Extract the value for the key called "mag"
                String magnitude = properties.getString("mag");

                // Extract the value for the key called "place"
                String location = properties.getString("place");

                // Extract the value for the key called "time"
                long time = properties.getLong("time");

                // Extract the value for the key called "url"
                String url = properties.getString("url");

                // Create a new {@link EarthquakeAdapter} object with the magnitude, location, time,
                // and url from the JSON response.
                Word earthquake = new Word(magnitude, location, time, url);

                // Add the new {@link EarthquakeAdapter} to the list of earthquakes.
                earthquakes.add(earthquake);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
            // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
            // with the message from the exception.
            Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
        }
        // Return the list of earthquakes
        return earthquakes;
    }

}
```

activity_list_display.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    tools:context="com.example.a.books.Word">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/magnitude"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="8.9" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location_offset"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:text="30km S of" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/primary_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Long placeholder location that should wrap to more than 2 lines of text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:text="Mar 6, 2010" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:text="3:00 PM" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_word.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.a.books">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".WordActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Word"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `ArrayList<Word> words` check words size

Comment: Did you debug response?

Comment: Where you have setted adapter?How many times you are calling that?

Comment: confused with this   mAdapter = new WordAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Word>());   final WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Word>()); notify ur adapter

Comment: @mertsimsek yes did it nothing found.

Comment: @SunishaSindhu see WordAdapter.java

Comment: @SunishaSindhu Added it still getting ablank screen.

Comment: @SunishaSindhu tried what you suggested above. Still the app screen is showing empty list views.

Comment: Just a tip, if you're fetching JSON correctly, you don't have to post that code since it's not directly relevant to the question

Comment: Yeah I know but I asked it previously everyone focused on json. So to avoid any confusion I stated it like this @Denny

Comment: Create a global listview object, set your adapter in onLoadfinished method because there your are filling up your data and then notifychanged method

Comment: @Bhavnik did that its not working.

Comment: just comment that mAdapter.clear and check

Comment: @SunishaSindhu yes someone suggested it. Still same :-(

Comment: wait let me try here with that URL

Comment: @SunishaSindhu waiting. Thanks

Comment: hey small doubt you properly given word activity to all na...i mean you layout i have seen tools:context="com.example.a.books.Word" ;activity_list_display.xml check here

Comment: Yes for sure @SunishaSindhu

Comment: got ouptput man

Comment: Please replace the code which am going to answer..and please if it is worked please vote it..problem with your adapter...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143841/discussion-between-sunisha-sindhu-and-parmeet-singh-anand).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 @Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Word>> loader, List<Word> earthquakes) {
    mAdapter.clear();

    if (earthquakes != null && !earthquakes.isEmpty()) {
          mAdapter = new WordAdapter(this, earthquakes)
    }

    if (earthquakeListView.getAdapter() != null) {
        if (earthquakeListView.getAdapter().getCount() == 0) {
            earthquakeListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    } else

    {
        earthquakeListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. Error: cannot resolve earthquakeListView

Comment: Its your listview object make it global .

Comment: Did it. Stll the screen is blank.

Comment: Wordadapter(this,earthquakes)                                            Error:WordAdapter
(Activity,
java.util.ArrayList<com.example.a.books.Word>)
in WordAdapter cannot be applied
to
(WordActivity,
java.util.List<com.example.a.books.Word>)

Comment: Modify your adapter constructor

Comment: After doing that blank list view is also gone. Now the app is totally blank.

Comment: Modify your adapter constructor 
public WordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Word> words) to
public WordAdapter(Activity context, List<Word> words)

Comment: Yes I did that. Its not working. Still not getting what I did wrong.

Comment: your sure earthquakes is not empty? put logs in this snippet and see how flow goes

Answer (score 1):

Screenshot is attaching,[image]Replace your code with this,

```
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WordActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Word>> {
    private static final int EARTHQUAKE_LOADER_ID = 1;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = WordActivity.class.getName();
    /**
     * URL for earthquake data from the USGS dataset
     */
    private static final String USGS_REQUEST_URL =
            "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2014-01-01&endtime=2014-01-02";
    /**
     * Adapter for the list of earthquakes
     */
    public wordAdap mAdapter;
    private TextView mEmptyStateTextView;
    ListView earthquakeListView;
    ArrayList<Word> words;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_word);
        // Get a reference to the LoaderManager, in order to interact with loaders.
        earthquakeListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1) ;
        words=new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new wordAdap(WordActivity.this, words);


        // Create a new adapter that takes an empty list of earthquakes as input


        // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
        // so the list can be populated in the user interface

        earthquakeListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Set an item click listener on the ListView, which sends an intent to a web browser
        // to open a website with more information about the selected earthquake.


        // Start the AsyncTask to fetch the earthquake data
        //mEmptyStateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        //earthquakeListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyStateTextView);
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // Get details on the currently active default data network
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        // If there is a network connection, fetch data
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            // Get a reference to the LoaderManager, in order to interact with loaders.
            LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();

            // Initialize the loader. Pass in the int ID constant defined above and pass in null for
            // the bundle. Pass in this activity for the LoaderCallbacks parameter (which is valid
            // because this activity implements the LoaderCallbacks interface).
            loaderManager.initLoader(EARTHQUAKE_LOADER_ID, null, this);
        } else {
            // Otherwise, display error
            // First, hide loading indicator so error message will be visible
            //View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
            //loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //Update empty state with no connection error message
            //mEmptyStateTextView.setText("No Connection");
        }

    }

    public Loader<List<Word>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new WordLoader(this, USGS_REQUEST_URL);
    }

    /**
     * {@link } to perform the network request on a background thread, and then
     * update the UI with the list of earthquakes in the response.
     * <p>
     * AsyncTask has three generic parameters: the input type, a type used for progress updates, and
     * an output type. Our task will take a String URL, and return an EarthquakeAdapter. We won't do
     * progress updates, so the second generic is just Void.
     * <p>
     * We'll only override two of the methods of AsyncTask: doInBackground() and onPostExecute().
     * The doInBackground() method runs on a background thread, so it can run long-running code
     * (like network activity), without interfering with the responsiveness of the app.
     * Then onPostExecute() is passed the result of doInBackground() method, but runs on the
     * UI thread, so it can use the produced data to update the UI.
     */

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Word>> loader, List<Word> earthquakes) {
        // Clear the adapter of previous earthquake data
        //View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
        //loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_earthquakes);
//        mAdapter.clear();
        // If there is a valid list of {@link Earthquake}s, then add them to the adapter's
        // data set. This will trigger the ListView to update.

        if (earthquakes != null && !earthquakes.isEmpty()) {
            words.addAll(earthquakes);
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

      /*  words.addAll(earthquakes);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Word>> loader) {
        // Loader reset, so we can clear out our existing data.
//        mAdapter.clear();
    }


}
```

And your adapter as,

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by sunisha on 10/5/17.
 */

public class wordAdap extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<Word> Word=new ArrayList<>();
    Activity mContext;

    public wordAdap(Activity context, ArrayList<Word> Word) {
        mContext = context;
        this.Word = Word;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Word.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return Word.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        final CampaignItemViewHolders holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_display, null);
//            v = li.inflate(R.layout.aa, null);
            holder = new CampaignItemViewHolders(v);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (CampaignItemViewHolders) v.getTag();
        }



        String magnitude=Word.get(position).getMagnitude();
        holder.magnitudeView.setText(magnitude);


        return v;
    }

}

class CampaignItemViewHolders {
    TextView magnitudeView;

    public CampaignItemViewHolders(View base) {

        magnitudeView = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.magnitude);



    }


}
```

Comment: i have just set magnitude only do the same way the other details okay....

Comment: Hey thanks you are awesome. Got some doubts first it is only showing magnitude. I am a beginner in Android development I really don't know which method you used to get the output.                                                 2) How to get other Json data?                                                                                    3) What was wrong in my code?                                                                         Voting up. Please explain and solve the rest also. Thanks alot.

Comment: Oh okay....I have added you in chat can you able to check that?http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143841/discussion-between-sunisha-sindhu-and-parmeet-singh-anand

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing a `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Word>> loader, List<Word> earthquakes) {
    mAdapter.clear();

    if (earthquakes != null && !earthquakes.isEmpty()) {
        mAdapter.addAll(earthquakes);
    }

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //<---- You're missing this
}
```

The `ArrayAdapter` only updates automatically when using add(), insert(), remove(), and clear()

Comment: Added it still getting a blank screen.